guest interface is not coming up after interface down and up. so lost the radio (ssid)
once down (using ifconfig down) the guest network on any interface (2g/5g/6G) that particular interface got lost the Ssid . After bringing up the particular interface (using ifconfig up), it doesn't have the ssid on bring up guest interface(2.4g / 5g/6G). Waiting for 30 mins even though the ssid is not coming up properly.
particular interface(guest-2.4/5/6) coming up properly after interface up. but at the hostapd side,
particular interface of radio is not starting (missing virtual guest (2.4/5/6) up at hostapd). for wlan(2.4/5/6) working properly but guest interface has this issue.
For down & up commands:

ifconfig guest-2400mhz down
ifconfig guest-2400mhz up

guest interface is not working ?....
